# scrollTop word in a text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the `scrollTop` from a specific word.

I tried that one :

```
    function findWords() {
        var str = $('body').html();
        var patt1 = /דת*/g;
        var result = str.match(patt1);
        console.log(result[0].scrollTop());
    }
```

But the browser keep telling me that there is no `scrollTop` function, how come?

> Object ד has no method 'scrollTop'

this is my HTML :

```
 <div class="mobileSampleDiv">
    <h1>כותרת כלשהי</h1>
    שתי לעריכה מיוחדים בויקיפדיה בה, מיזם בארגז וכמקובל שמו את, מה אחר רוסית לערוך תיקונים. שער לכאן וקשקש של, על לעברית לויקיפדים טכנולוגיה דת. שכל שתפו אינו בה, של כלל זכויות שינויים, אם בקר החלל טבלאות. תנך טיפול פיסול או, אחרות ומדעים ביוטכנולוגיה ב סדר, יוצרים מאמרשיחהצפה מה שמו. אחד על כדור שינויים פסיכולוגיה, על דת העזרה משחקים רבה.
```

**Edit**:  *I do have a JQuery ref in my project*

Comment: `scrollTop()` is a Jquery function, so you may need to include Jquery lib .ref:http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: Also, it seems you're calling the function from a simple string. I think you need to call it from an object. Like $('someobject').scrollTop();

Comment: I do have an jquery ref in my project.  worthed mention...

Comment: Please post corresponding HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollTop works on a jQuery wrapped set. From the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/):

> **Description**: Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for
>   the first element in the set of matched elements or set the vertical
>   position of the scroll bar for every matched element.

When you call `.html()` you basically get a simple string with no reference to anything.
Your code is operating on strings, which are not bound to any specific DOM element.

You are not able to perform freetext searches in this manner. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you may embed a hidden anchor or similar next to the ד, and invite `scrollTop()` on that:

Anchor:

```
<a id="locateMe"/>
```

Script:

```
$("#locateMe").scrollTop();
```

If you are unable to place an anchor like this, but know something about the html structure of the page, you may be able to build a query for any element of the desired type with a certain property containing the character you are looking for, and call `scrollTop()` on that. It all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: can I wrap the string "on the fly" using jquery ?   I dont have access to the HTML so I cant pre-anchor it. (can I replace the body of the html when it loads and then wrap it with anchors that fits for me?

Comment: I have not tried this, but maybe this article could be of use: http://teeohhem.com/2011/02/20/search-for-and-highlight-text-on-a-page-with-jquery/ - basically it does something like this: $(body).html($(body).html().replace(searchTerm, "<a id='locateMe'>"+searchTerm+"</span>")); (not sure if there is a prettyer way, though)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$(result).scrollTop();
```

Explaination:

> $(selector).scrollTop(position);
>   where
>   position : Specifies the vertical scrollbar position in pixels

P.S. you will have to use $() to select the element as scrolltop is jquery fn
else you will have to use

Element.scrollTop
ie.

```
result.scrollTop
```